# How can i know the page is runing in browser or not?

Tags: php

how can I know the page is really opened in brower or  get from script or src="xxx"?

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])){
    $_SESSION['count']=0;
}

// I don't want to
// if(open in brower){
    $_SESSION['count']++;
// }
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:{},
        success:function(){}
    });
</script>
<?php 
    echo $_SESSION['count'] ; // the result now is 1,3,5,... for every reload
    // I want to get the result 1,2,3,4... for every reload , how to check the page is really open in brower? not run in ajax or get ?

?>
```

Comment: This is most probably an XY problem, but you can usually tell from the HTTP_ACCEPT server variable.

Comment: As opposed to what...?

Comment: Note sure why moderate hold this question, without asking for clarification. Anyways, jQuery send `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` Header in each ajax request, you can check for if header is present, and then put your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this specific example would be to pass some data to the ajax request, and check that the data ISN'T present in order to increase your session count.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])){
    $_SESSION['count']=0;
}

if(!isset($_GET['dontcount'])){
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:{'dontcount',1},
        success:function(){}
    });
</script>
<?php 
    echo $_SESSION['count'];

?>
```

Comment: can write some code down?

Comment: added code to the answer